# Error limitación temporal o una expiración en Epplus en licencia no comercial C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, epplus

he estado trabajando con la libreria de epplus sin ningun problema hasta hace poco, y me gustaria preguntarles sobre un error o mas bien saber si realmente lo que me pasa ya les esta pasando a todos, hasta ahora nunca me habia preocupado por estar constantemente actualizando la biblioteca de Epplus en mi proyecto pero ultimamente ya van dos veces que me pasa que despues de un mes al no actualizar a una version mas nueva mi biblioteca y queriendo usar mis metodos donde uso esta biblioteca, me manda un mensaje de error donde me dice que el timpo ya expiro, y actualizando la biblioteca deja de mandar ese error y funciona normalmente. Esto es normal? o es nuevo?

Estuve investigando pero no encontre nada sobre esto :(
Saludos, espero y me puedan ayudar un poco.